# "umgekehrt als bei" oder "umgekehrt wie bei"?

Tags: grammar, comparison

In folgendem Satz:

> Bei X ist das anders als bei Y.

muss das Wort *als* verwendet werden, sagt mir mein Sprachgefühl. Ich hadere aber etwas bei:

> Bei X ist das umgekehrt als bei Y.

Ich würde sagen auch hier muss *als* stehen, aber mir wurde gesagt, es müsse *wie* heißen. Was ist richtig und warum?

Comment: egal, was da jezt richtig ist... für mich klingt beides naja... nicht so toll, und ich würde immer versuchen anders zu formulieren... zum Beispiel mit "andersherum als" :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nach [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/als_in_Vergleichen) gehört zu einem Vergleich in dem man die **Ungleichheit** ausdrückt die Konjunktion *"als"*:

> **1.b.** bei Ungleichheit nach andere, anders, nichts, kein, niemand, ***umgekehrt***, entgegengesetzt oder nach einem Fragepronomen [+ sonst, überhaupt u. a.]

Demnach sollte der Beispielsatz wie folgt richtig sein:

> Bei X ist das umgekehrt als bei Y.

---

Interessanterweise wird aber bis in die 70er-Jahre bei der Verwendung mit "**umgekehrt**" viel häufiger "**wie**" denn "**als**" gesehen:

[image]

<sup>[Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=umgekehrt%20als,umgekehrt%20wie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3)</sup>

Auch in renommierten Zeitungen findet man auch heute noch *"umgekehrt wie"*:

> Ein Fusionsreaktor funktioniert gewissermaßen umgekehrt wie ein herkömmliches Atomkraftwerk.<sup>[Die Zeit 31, 2011](http://www.zeit.de/2011/31/Fusionsenergie)</sup>
>   Das heißt "Bonus Plus" und funktioniert genau umgekehrt wie das Kundenbindungsprogramm der Bahn. <sup>[Die Zeit 2009](http://www.zeit.de/online/2009/21/glossar-bahnisch)</sup>
>   Denn bei den SPD-Spitzenkandidaten lief es im Laufe der Jahre - mit Ausnahme eines kleinen Ausreißers unter Renate Schmidt - genau umgekehrt wie bei Ude: Ihre Wahlergebnisse wurden von Mal zu Mal schlechter.<sup>[Süddeutsche 2011](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/muenchen/ude-gegen-seehofer-reize-jenseits-der-routine-1.1129298)</sup>

Man kann also ***"umgekehrt wie"*** nicht ohne weiteres als falsch bezeichnen. Dennoch ist ***"umgekehrt als"*** die grammatikalisch-logisch richtigere oder auch modernere Variante, wie auch das obige Ngram schön zeigt.

Comment: Könnte daran liegen, dass umgekehrt sowas wie *ist ungleich wie* entspricht und kein Vergleich im Sinne von größer/kleiner/mehr/weniger. Macht's natürlich nicht richtig(er), aber ist nur ein Erklärungsversuch.

Comment: Das Ngram könnte trügerisch sein, weil "als" vs. "wie" von vielen leuten gerne verwechselt wird. Dass es viel benutzt wird, heißt nicht dass es korrekt ist (siehe "wegen"+Dativ).

Comment: @bitmask: Klar ist das Ngram nur ein Trend, wir haben leider nichts besseres - immerhin findet man aber doch z.B. in "Die Zeit" in den 60er Jahren weitaus mehr *"umgekehrt wie"* als heute. Irgendetwas ist da schon dran.

Comment: Das Ngram wirft mehr Fragen auf als es beantwortet: warum ist der überschaubare Anstieg bei "als"  (Stagnieren wäre wohl der bessere Ausdruck) viel geringer als der Abfall bei "wie"?

Comment: @guidot: ein Ngram kann niemals Fragen beantworten, allenfalls Antworten illustrieren und genau zu diesem Zweck hatte ich das damals **vor drei Jahren** (!!!) auch hier veröffentlicht.

Comment: [Wortschatz Leizig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=288215) zeigt das gleiche Bild - ungefähr gleich selten. Beide Varianten profitieren von einer Umformulierung.

Answer (score 7):

Die Situation mit *wie* und *als* ist etwas vertrackter, als dass man sie mit der Frage nach der Gleichheit bereits beantwortet hätte.

Man kann mit der Gleichsetzung, die das *wie* verlangt, eine Ungleichheit ausdrücken. Der Vater wiegt 4-mal so viel **wie** der Sohn, mit anderen Worten: 3-mal mehr **als** dieser. Man verzeihe mir den Ausflug in mathematische Notation:

- *v* = 4 *s*
- *v* = *s* + (3 *s*)

Der Weg von Berlin nach Paris ist, wie wir jetzt leicht einsehen, umgekehrt wie der Weg Paris – Berlin. Wird einer umgekehrt ist er wie der andere.

Anders als beim amorphen Anderssein ist der Weg nicht umgekehrt **als** der andere.

Comment: Genau deshalb ist *"umgekehrt wie"* auch nicht falsch. Aber der Duden (s.o.) sagt eindeutig, dass nach *"umgekehrt"* in der Verwendung zum Ausdruck einer Ungleichheit **als** zu folgen hat.

Comment: +1 Das ist ein wirklich guter Punkt.

Comment: @Takkat: An anderer Stelle erweise ich dem Duden gerne meine Referenz. Hier zögere ich zu folgen.

Comment: *Wird einer umgekehrt ist er wie der andere* ist in diesem Zusammenhang kein gutes Beispiel. Denn hier kommt das *wie* nicht wegen des *umgekehrt*, sondern aus dem Schema *das eine ist wie das andere*. Man kann nicht sagen *das eine ist als das andere*.

Answer (score 2):

> [umgekehrt als](http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/als-wie)

ist korrekt. "Als" wird bei Ungleichheit verwendet (*größer als*), "wie" bei Gleicheit (*so groß wie*). "Umgekehrt" ist ein Ungleichheit, daher ist "als" korrekt.

Comment: "Ähnlich wie" passt da nicht recht in das Schema...

Answer (score 0):

Seltsamerweise schmerzt beides mein inneres Ohr, und ich versuche gewöhnlich, mit Hilfe von z. B:

> hier verhält sich die Sache genau umgekehrt (andersherum, entgegengesetzt) gegenüber dem zuvor Beschriebenen

auszuweichen. Schwach und unbefriedigend, was die Ausgangsfrage betrifft, ich weiß.

Gefühlsmäßig neige ich bei *umgekehrt* eine Winzigkeit mehr zu *wie*. 
Es ist, als trüge das Wort *umgekehrt* den gesamten Vergleichsprozess, der sich ansonsten bei Gleichem aus einem *so* (*genauso*) und dem *wie* sowie bei Ungleichem aus einem Komparativ und dem *als* zusammensetzt, bereits in sich selbst und würde ihn zugleich innerlich beantworten oder auflösen. Daher kommt mir das *wie* vielleicht ein wenig eher entgegen.

Es scheint mir, als bedürfe es hier einer (mir unbekannten) *neutralen* Konjunktion, die sich des Urteils über *gleich* oder *ungleich* quasi enthält, weil *umgekehrt* die vorliegenden Verhältnisse erschöpfend beschreibt, aber mit einer Konjunktion dennoch an das im Satz Nachfolgende angeknüpft werden soll.

Was würden Sie alternativ davon halten, auf eine Konjunktion ganz zu verzichten, also *X ist umgekehrt Y*? Das wird schon schwieriger erträglich, sobald eine sprachliche Verfeinerung einsetzt wie bei unserem „Bei X ist das umgekehrt als bei Y.“ So kann ich also leider auch keine Antwort liefern, würde mich aber freuen, wenn meine Gedanken zu weiterer Diskussion beitragen könnten.